# Load dynamic content based on user's credentials?

Tags: http, windows-7, iis-7.5, webdav, httpmodule

Is it possible, using `WebDAV`, to load dynamic content for each user (for example, maybe *their files* from *our database*) who maps their drive to our `WebDAV` share?

Every WebDAV implementation I've seen uses a Virtual Directory in `IIS`, and lets users map a network drive to that directory, ultimately syncing files/folders between the two.

What I'd like to do, if possible, is use `WebDAV` to let a user map their drive to a Virtual Directory, but only use the Virtual Directory for the sake of mapping their drive. I've got an `HttpModule` set up that will execute on `WebDAV` requests, so my idea was to let the `HttpModule` decide, based on the user, what files need to be loaded and create the virtual folder structure in their mapped drive from there.

Since multiple users will be accessing this drive, I don't actually want `WebDAV` to sync files back and forth between the Virtual Directory and the user's mapped drive. The idea is that we'll let the `HttpModule` detect what folder the user is in (from the request) and then load the files in from our database accordingly.

Is this possible? Or is there an alternative way to accomplish this? I realize that this may be using `WebDAV` for something other than it was intended for, but I wasn't sure if there were any other ways to let a user map a drive like this and detect requests coming from Windows Explorer. I'm using IIS 7.5 with VB.NET on Windows 7 currently for testing. I'll also need to implement security/authentication eventually, I was just hoping to get it working on a basic level first, so that's one thing to keep in mind.

**UPDATE:**

I've added `RequestFiltering` to my Web.config to not allow files with the extension ".txt" in hopes that they wouldn't get copied down to my local mapped drive (I copied a few text files into my Virtual Directory in IIS), but that wasn't the case - they always show up in the mapped drive. It appears that the `RequestFiltering` doesn't actually affect files showing up in my mapped drive, but instead just doesn't allow me to open them.

Is there a way to have `WebDAV` enabled for the sake of having a mapped drive to the share, but not allowing `WebDAV` to show/copy the files in the mapped drive? I'd like for it to work the same both ways, i.e. when copying files into the mapped drive, they shouldn't be copied into the Virtual Directory in `IIS`. I'd like to intercept those requests and handle copying the files to a different location (or into a database).

Comment: Something like this http://thehojusaram.blogspot.com/2007/06/c-webdav-server-with-sql-backend-source.html

Comment: That looks exactly like what I'll need! Thank you. I am having some issues with IIS and posted another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917230/iis-7-classic-mode-route-all-extensions-and-verbs-to-aspnet-isapi As soon as I get my IIS issue figured out, I'll be able to test this solution.

Comment: Regardless of my IIS issues before, this is going to be what I needed to do. I've downloaded the project from your link and have began looking through the code, pulling out what I need. If you post that link as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went with was to download the project from the [link](http://thehojusaram.blogspot.com/2007/06/c-webdav-server-with-sql-backend-source.html) provided above by @User629926 and follow the logic of that project. The project clearly demonstrates how to use `HttpModules` & `HttpHandlers` to intercept `WebDAV` requests, and then dynamically build the response which allows me to display the back-end SQL data in Windows Explorer.